# Is it possible for emacs to load a buffer from a Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: emacs, amazon-s3

Is it possible for emacs to load a buffer from a Amazon S3 bucket? If so has somebody already built something that can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)?

In which case, you could do something like (untested):

```
(defun grab-s3-bucket (url)
  (interactive "sURL for Amazon s3 bucket: ")
  (shell-command (format "curl -O %s" url) (get-buffer-create url)))

M-x grab-s3-bucket URL
```

You could write the results back with something like:

```
(defun write-s3-bucket (url)
  (interactive "sURL for Amazon s3 bucket: ")
  (shell-command-on-region (format "curl %s -T " url)))
```

You could even get tricky and bind <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to the `write-s3-bucket`, using a buffer local variable to store the URL for the s3 bucket (that would get created upon the call to `grab-s3-bucket`).

Comment: @simao He didn't specify he wanted to write the contents, just to load them.  But fine, I'll augment the proposed solution for writing as well.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [S3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) to mount a local filesystem mapped to a s3 drive and access the file normally with emacs.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to eval the file as well, you can do this:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (shell-command "wget -q -O- URL_TO_FILE" (current-buffer))
  (eval-buffer))
```